# What will be the best to increase the speed of the computer i.e. RAM should be increased or SSD should be installed in the computer

Tags: linux, windows-7, memory, ssd, dualboot

I have Dell,i5 laptop 7th generation windows and I am a android developer and we know android studio requires a lot of memory. So, to increase the working speed of my computer what should be done. I should increase the RAM from 4GB to 8GB or i should install a SSD in the system, of 256GB and one more thing is that i have a dual boot(windows and linux) system so having a dual boot system affects the speed of the System ?

Comment: Android Studio needs everything fast and large: large RAM, fast SSD; fast CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be closed as 'opinion-based', but before that happens I would like
once and for all to say that smart upgrading requires knowledge of what the
computer is doing.

Use the Task Manager and the Resource Monitor and Process Explorer:
See which resources are stretched to the limit among CPU, RAM and disk.
Then improve one element *only* and check again.

If CPU is close to saturated - improve it. If RAM is full - add more.
If the disk is very busy - find on which file, if the pagefile then add RAM,
if other then get an SSD.

Blindly choosing an improvement is a waste of money. If you are unsure,
then just buy a computer that is better on all counts.

Answer (score 2):

This may get closed as 'opinion-based' but before that happens - you need both.

4GB RAM is really too small these days, I'd call 8GB minimum & 16 starts to get comfortable. An SSD will vastly improve your throughput, but don't skimp. Get at least 512GB or you'll be constantly trying to figure out which things you can afford to delete.

Dual booting has no effect on either OS when it's running, other than to eat up some of that too-small 256GB SSD.